# What connector will fit this?

Tags: connector, identification, fluid-pump

Does anyone perhaps know what type of connector this is please? It's 8-pin but not a normal DIN connector. It's the remote control port for a peristaltic pump. I've asked the manufacturer for the connection type - they refuse to tell me, and only offer their own cable for £25 + c£100 in minimum order charges!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have dimensions on it? What's the spacing between pins, overall size of the connector, etc?

Comment: If you can take it apart, you might find a PN written somewhere. It will help to find the mating connector

Comment: A brief search on digikey revealed these two connectors that it _might_ be: [\[1\]](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/conxall-switchcraft/SF6282-8PG-520/SC1345-ND/2089789) [\[2\]](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/MXR-8P-8P-72/HR1825-ND/1202884)

Comment: Might be a twist-lock water-/weather-proof connector.

Comment: By the time you're done, their own cable will look like a pretty good deal.

Comment: @BrianDrummond That's going a bit far I think haha!

Comment: @Felthry Its a bit tricky to get the calipers into, but the width of the socket face is 11.3mm.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You can take it apart, but the warranty is void

Comment: It is common to make a special connector for medical devices as ISO 14971 says that you need to address that the medical device may be deliberately misused - and suggests that you consider incorrect use of connectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the standard circular connector. Also know to the aviation guys as a "cannon plug" the 8-14 pin arrangement came in different diameter sizes. so you need to measure the diameter of the inner insulator (where the pins are mounted) so we can size it.  Also there should be a part number on the backside of this connector which would be easier to source your plugs. the important numbers are going to be on the end of this part number (in example, a uts6jc12e8s is a size 12e 8 pin socket connector)

usually on panel mount connectors the part number will be stamped on the backside of the panel flange, so you will need to loosen the back mounting nut and pull the connector out from the front side and look for it with a little inspection mirror.

Comment: OK thanks drtechno. I managed to measure to insulator as 11.3mm diameter. You can't take the face off to get to the back of the socket without voiding the warranty. I will try this https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/WD19-GX20-Aviation-Plug-Socket-Circular-Multipole-Connector-Bulkhead-3-Hole/151916850289?var=451101167272&hash=item235ef32c71:m:me8v4mIY2jOyZtOMnT6tkHA

Answer (score 0):

Probably an [8 pin M12](http://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/circular-connectors/intersection/m8m12.html?tab=pgp-story) connector. Check dimensions before ordering.

[image]

Comment: I don't know, that key looks a bit large...